# How to parse json int array?

Tags: c, json

I want to parse a JSON `int` array into my C program. Here is how my input look like.

```
"category" : { "list" : [1, 2, 3, 4], "count" : 4}.
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always write your own JSON parsing algorithm, but why reinvent the wheel? There are some good JSON libraries available for C which can do that for you. See http://www.json.org/ for lists of JSON libraries for all common programming languages (it has 14 different ones for C to choose from).

Comment: I am currently doing it as                             
category = get_json_child_from_parent(bid_obj, "category" , json_type_object);

category_list = get_json_child_from_parent(category, "list", json_type_array);
count  =  get_json_child_from_parent(category, "count", json_type_int);
count = count->o.c_int;
list = malloc( count->o.c_int* sizeof(int));
for(j = 0; j < count->o.c_int; j++){
iterator = json_object_array_get_idx(category_list, j);
list[j] = iterator->o.c_int;
}
but some unintialized int is assigned to list. How can I access the int array?